# Chrome extension: Javascript content script does not have access to HTML elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've looked at some similar threads in SO but I couldn't understand the solutions.
Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Test  5",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
        "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["jquery-2.0.3.min.map"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.google.es/*"
            ],
            "js":         ["jquery.js", "content_scripts.js"],
            "run_at":     "document_end",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**content_scripts.js**

```
var doFilter = function() { 
    var classR = document.getElementsByClassName("rc");
    console.log("2");
    console.log("classR: "+classR.length );
        //...etc
}

$(window).load(function() {
    console.log("1");
    doFilter(document.body);    
});
```

The code is already loaded as a Chrome unpacked extension. I'm using Dev Tools in Chrome to debug it from the local files in my PC.

When having Dev Tools opened in the same tab as the web browser, I browse to "www.google.es" and I search for some keyword. 
Then I'm able to see in Dev Tools console logs. The problem is that the last one shows that classR has length 0.
[image]
[image]

As you can see, there are elements by class name "rc", so it seems

> document.getElementsByClassName("rc")

is actually not accessing to the loaded HTML document.
What am I missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know when Google search results page renders its results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582991/how-to-know-when-google-search-results-page-renders-its-results)

Comment: Google populates the DOM asynchronously, so at the time you are looking there are indeed no `.rc` elements. Take a look at **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582991/how-to-know-when-google-search-results-page-renders-its-results)** for a more detailed explanation and sample code.

Comment: Oh thanks, that approach is fine!