# Monitor for Page Changes

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events, content-script

I'm writing a Chrome extension for Stack Overflow, and need to rerun a check when the page updates (i.e. comments/answers are added to the content).

I've tried subscribing to `$(document).ajaxComplete()`, but that never seems to fire.

I've found that binding to `DOMSubtreeModified` allows me to update correctly, but it appears to be firing *too* often. On a page load, it can be called 21 times (Sometimes it is only called once though). Equally, if I perform a jquery selection in the console, the event fires again multiple times.

```
$(setup);

var hits = 0;
var original_title;

function setup()
{
    original_title = document.title;
    doWork();
}

function doWork()
{
    //unbind so our own changes don't cause infinite loops of the event.
    $("#mainbar").unbind("DOMSubtreeModified", findSkeets);

    //Debug: Add the Number of function hits to the title bar
    hits++;
    document.title = "(" + hits + ") " + original_title;

    //Do Work Here
    
    //Rebind to the event now that we've finished executing;
    $("#mainbar").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", findSkeets);
}
```

Is there a more efficient method of monitoring for changes to the page? I've seen a couple of Chrome hangs on Stack Overflow, that might be a result of this extension, so I'd like to minimise the impact as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMSubtreeModified` is part of the obsolete **[Mutation Events API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events)**, which has been deprecated (among other reasons) for being *notoriously inefficient*. According to MDN, `DOM Mutation Events`is a feature that  *"has been removed from the Web"*, *"is in the process of being dropped"* and *"Web apps using it may break at any time"*.

You should use the new **[MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)**, which is also more efficient.
(The **[mutation-summary](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/)** library now provides a useful inteface to this new API.)

See, also, **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560819/chrome-extension-fire-an-event-when-element-created#19767155)** for more details and **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582991/how-to-know-when-google-search-results-page-renders-its-results#20583279)** for a similar usecase: A Chrome Extension using the MutationObserver API to detect (and decorate) asynchronously loaded Google search results.

Comment: You sir, are my hero! Thanks for that. I'll need to bear it in mind for future too.